# Fill data-frame by matching its rows with the multiple level of another dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data-frames df1, a multi-level data-frames and df2 do not have any levels. I want to add the columns to the df2 by matching the multi-levels of df1 with the rows of df2.

Code below works fine, but it converts df2 to to multi-level dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'step 0': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.372621, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.10471400000000002, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.144627, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.49122200000000005, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.08583099999999999, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.3366, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.235332, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.030488, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.827896, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.061280999999999995, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.124464, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.0}, 'step 1': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.21143499999999998, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.10622899999999999, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.270593, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.065209, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.18825799999999998, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.328942, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.18970499999999998, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.448532, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.371369, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.272635, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.251659, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.381712, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.189613, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.223804, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.252529, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.045514, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.034437999999999996, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.239879}, 'step 2': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.162299, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.119725, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.5406270000000001, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.060129999999999996, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.158279, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.233738, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.314877, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.5514680000000001, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.24836799999999998, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.171224, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.190137, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.30941399999999997, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.351985, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.172104, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.611961, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.171979, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.388104, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.125909, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.25806399999999996}, 'step 3': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.149502, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.172926, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.18878, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.272958, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.162242, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.242986, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.15881800000000001, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.751632, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.22207399999999997, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.153442, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.43892700000000007, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.266302, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.198426, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.271795, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.23490300000000003, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.190519, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.502057}, 'step 4': {('D1', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.104143, ('D1', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.49640500000000004, ('D1', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.45707600000000004, ('D1', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.108503, ('D1', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D1', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S1'): 0.353298, ('D2', 'E1', 'S2'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S3'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'S4'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E1', 'Unknown'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'S1'): 0.27114, ('D2', 'E2', 'S2'): 0.0, ('D2', 'E2', 'S3'): 0.638058, ('D2', 'E2', 'S4'): 0.965562, ('D2', 'E2', 'Unknown'): 0.0}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'DT':['D1','D1','D2','D2','D1','D2'], 'RE':['E1','E1','E1','E2','E1','E1'], 'DS':['S1','S2','S2','S3','S1','S2']})
df2 = df2[['DT', 'RE', 'DS']]
print(df1)
print(df2)
m_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df2.T.values)
m = pd.DataFrame(index=m_idx, columns=df1.columns)
m.update(df1)
print(m)
```

output of `print(m)`:

```
            step 0    step 1    step 2    step 3    step 4
D1 E1 S1  0.372621  0.211435  0.162299  0.149502  0.104143
      S2  0.104714  0.106229  0.119725  0.172926  0.496405
D2 E1 S2         0  0.251659  0.309414  0.438927         0
   E2 S3         0  0.045514  0.125909  0.190519  0.638058
D1 E1 S1  0.372621  0.211435  0.162299  0.149502  0.104143
D2 E1 S2         0  0.251659  0.309414  0.438927         0
```

I want to add the columns in df2 like this:

```
  DE RE DS    step 0    step 1    step 2    step 3    step 4
0 D1 E1 S1  0.372621  0.211435  0.162299  0.149502  0.104143
1 D1 E1 S2  0.104714  0.106229  0.119725  0.172926  0.496405
2 D2 E1 S2         0  0.251659  0.309414  0.438927         0
3 D2 E2 S3         0  0.045514  0.125909  0.190519  0.638058
4 D1 E1 S1  0.372621  0.211435  0.162299  0.149502  0.104143
5 D2 E1 S2         0  0.251659  0.309414  0.438927         0
```

Comment: Why doesn't `m.reset_index()` work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `reindex` with `reset_index`

```
df1.reindex(df2.set_index(df2.columns.tolist()).index).reset_index()
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 first create the index I am using the set index method, then all index value in the index of empty df, then reindex the df1 to get index match of the index create from df2